# Error While publishing Azure Cloud service with .net 4.6

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, .net-4.6

Error : "The feature named NetFx46 that is required by the uploaded package is not available in the OS * chosen for the deployment."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Service Configuration files (*.cscfg) change osFamily="4" to osFamily="5".

Comment: Also if you deploy via Visual Studio - check if you use Microsoft Azure SDK 2.9.6 or later.